# Access97 Compare two Dates

Tags: php, sql, date

I'm trying to compare 2 dates with an SQL Query,

My query is this :

```
"SELECT table.toto
FROM table
WHERE 
table.date < $date"
```

`$date` is a variable that comes from my PHP code

In my table, my date is formatted like this : `dd/mm/YYYY`

Unfortunately, it doesn't work as expected, it returns only one result (it's supposed to return way more results), which date is : `1312-09-15 00:00:00` but in database, the date is formatted like dd/mm/YYYY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a solution to my problem.

I don't know why but I just have set the "$date" format to : `n/d/Y`
and to wrap it between "#" in code like this :

```
"SELECT table.toto 
FROM table
WHERE 
table.date < #date#"
```